# My JQuery script is not retrieving form text values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the data from a form and use the values for a final result.

The problem is (at least what it looks like when I'm debugging) is no values are being retried and stored in the vars I've created.

Here's the form:

```
<form>
    <p>
       <label for="numDigits">Number of Digits: </label>
       <input type="text" id="numDigits" name="numDigits" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="num1">First Number: </label>
        <input type="text" id="num1" name="num1" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="num2">Second Number: </label>
        <input type="text" id="num2" name="num2" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="num3">Third Number: </label>
        <input type="text" id="num3" name="num3" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="calc" id="calc" value="Calculate" />
    </p>
    <p id="result">Result will be displayed here when the button is pressed.</p>
</form>
```

and the JQuery script

```
$("#calc").on('click', function(){
    var a = Number($("#numDigits").val());
    var x = Number($("#num1").val());
    var y = Number($("#num2").val());
    var z = Number($("#num3").val());

    var total = a * 3 + x + ((a + x - y) % a) + ((a + z - y) % a);
    $("#result").html("<p class='id'>" + total + "</p>");
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

**Edit**: I updated the code to the working version.

Comment: How exactly did you debug the code? Seems to "work" for me (I get output at least): http://jsfiddle.net/D3JpS/.

Comment: I was debugging in WebStorm and saw that no values were being assigned. The weird number that shows up in Firefox and the -1 in Chrome are apparently the result of NaN or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems to work well: [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/OHOLOzu/1/edit?html,js,output)

But note that, if you want to manipulate the input as numbers, you should write

```
var a = Number($("#numDigits").val());
var x = Number($("#num1").val());
var y = Number($("#num2").val());
var z = Number($("#num3").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the replaceWith() with html(). I have The **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ijEHamU/1/edit)** working:

```
$("#calc").click(function(){
var a = $("#numDigits").val();
var x = $("#num1").val();
var y = $("#num2").val();
var z = $("#num3").val();

var total = a * 3 + x;
total += ((y - x) % a);
total += ((y - z) % a);
$("#result").html(total);
});
```

Comment: It turns out I needed to cast the vals as Numbers, but the HTML suggestion did help with updating the result for each time the script was run. Thanks!